# Base Url is not working in live in yii

Tags: yii

In localhost i have given baseurl in yii like this

```
        <?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>
```

It is working in local but not working in live.

please give your opinion

Comment: Have you enabled modrewrite?

Comment: I have used this baseurl in live <?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?> but not working in live

Answer (score 1):

You missed the request part in between -

```
 <?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>
```

Comment: i have tried this <?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?> also but it is not working in live

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php echo yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);?>
```

output:http://www.example.com

```
  <?php echo yii::app()->getBaseUrl(false);?>
```

output:www.example.com